# React-Redux mapStateToProps TypeError Cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know this error is very common in this community, however I'm left dumbfounded at something so stupid. when I try to connect mapState and mapDispatch and finish my redux hard boiled code I get a typeError when I try to fetch the state to be used as props in my component

a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-roentgen-j4igf?file=/src/AppWrapper.js

the code itself:

index.js:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { reducer } from "./Redux";
import AppWrapper from "./AppWrapper";

const store = createStore(reducer);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppWrapper />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

AppWrapper.js:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
import { getInputValue } from "./Redux";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
   {
    searchString: state.searchString
  }
)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    filterByValue: (e) => {
      let input = e.target.value;
      dispatch(getInputValue({ value: input }));
    },
    triggerUserValue: () => {
      dispatch({type: "TRIGGER_USER_VALUE"});
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";
import TemplateCard from "./TemplateCard";
import React from "react";
import { initialState } from "./Redux";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          placeholder="filter items"
          onChange={this.props.filterByValue}
        />

        <button onClick={this.props.triggerUserValue}> click me </button>

        {initialState.productData.map((i) => {
          return (
            <TemplateCard
              key={i.id}
              title={i.title}
              text={i.text}
              price={i.price}
              imageurl={i.imageurl}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Redux.js:

```
export const initialState = {
  searchString: "",
  anotherthingy: "",
  productData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Roses",
      title: "Roses",
      text: "Beautiful hand picked roses fresh out of our gardins",
      price: 9.99
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Dahlia",
      title: "Dahlia",
      text: "Beautiful hand picked Dahlia fresh out of our gardins",
      price: 17.99
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Alstroemerias",
      title: "Alstroemerias",
      text: "Beautiful hand picked Alstroemerias fresh out of our gardins",
      price: 12.99
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Calla lillies",
      title: "Calla lillies",
      text: "Beautiful hand picked Calla lillies fresh out of our gardins",
      price: 16.99
    }
  ]
};

export const getInputValue = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: "FILTER_BY_VALUE",
    payload
  };
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FILTER_BY_VALUE":
      let value = action.payload.value;
      console.log(value);
      return { ...state, searchString: value };
    case "TRIGGER_USER_VALUE":
      alert(state.searchString);
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are importing App from `./App`. You need to import from `./AppWrapper`.
Second, you don't pass `initialState`  in the `reducer` so the state doesn't have the initial value so this error occurs. You just need add `initialState` in reducer like this:

```
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {...}
```

Comment: I knew that it was something stupid. That you for clarifying that to me. However I don't see an issue with the imports, could you clarify that please?

Comment: If you use App from "./App", you cannot get data or dispatch action from redux because it doesn't connect with redux

Comment: The only place I imported "./App" was in AppWrapper.js, Wouldn't changing that to "./AppWrapper.js" break the code?